# Populating multiple table data in multiple dropdownlists on one page in ASP.Net MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, asp.net-mvc-4, html.dropdownlistfor

Being a newbie, please excuse my trivial question. (ASP.Net MVC4)

After reading lots of posts/tutorials I am still not sure about how to approach. What I am trying to do is have three **Dropdownlists** on my **Index** page. For instance, **Country, Company, Branch**. I have same data model for them which are linked to my database using EF. I have managed to just list all the data on the Index Page. However I need them inside the dropdownlist.

Question is how do I create the controller for that? Currently the controller looks like:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private CorpCostEntities db = new CorpCostEntities();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    ...
    ...

}
```

Do I need to create separate **ActionResult** methods for each table to populate data? Or do I use method overload for Index(), such as Index(Country country), Index(Company comp), Index(Branch branch)?

Next question is since there will be difefernt ActionResult methods, do I need to create separate Views for that? I am using simple MVC structure. I don't have ViewModel or something other than MVC.

What exactly the approach to first create the controller for a multiple dropdownlists and then show them in an existing View page?

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you shouldn't need a separate action for each type, I would just toss those values in the ViewBag and read in the view ([Here is how to load it into dropdown element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642821/mvc3-dropdownlist-viewbag-issue)):

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private CorpCostEntities db;

```
public HomeController(){
db = new CorpCostEntities();
ViewBag.CountryList = db.GetCountryList();
ViewBag.CompanyList = db.GetCompanyList();
ViewBag.BranchList = db.GetBranchList();
}
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

}

Regarding "Next question is since there will be difefernt ActionResult methods, do I need to create separate Views for that?", I am kind of unclear as to what you are asking, but I will give it a go on assumptions....Think of your (GET)ActionResults as pages (your action methods aren't just locked into returning 'pages', but bear with me).  Say you have a Action "index" that displays a list of Customers, you would have your Index Action and Index view.  Now, add an Edit screen, that will be another Action, Edit, and View, Edit.cshtml.

Comment: Thanks. Really appreciate your help @TNCodeMonkey. What I meant was each ActionResult method seems for each View. Like Index(), Index.cshtml. If I have everything on my Index page (e.g. filters for report generation) do I then just create one View page and put everything inside the Index() method?

Comment: @shaz no problem at all, glad we got another one over to ASP.NET MVC :).  If all you need is one page, that would work just fine for you;  if your users will come to the index page and interact solely within it.  I generally combine a mix of View methods and Operational/Functional methods within my controllers, as I am heavy into jQuery, JS, and AJAX, so that works for me.  In the end, it really boils down to what you need for your application, what you know, and what you are comfortable with.

Comment: Indeed. Being a newbie in ASP.Net MVC with disorganised documentation all over the place doesn't help much I am afraid. I need only Index page and a grid view to populate Search Result into it.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to consider to create a ViewModel (CorpCastViewModel) that contains all objects needed to render the view.

You would then have a propertie for the actual CorpCostModel, but also properties for your lookup collections and other stuff you need in your view.

Than you can create an editor as follows:
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CorpCostModel.SomeField)
and a listbox as
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CorpCostModel.CorpCountryId, new SelectList(Model.CountryList, "CountryId", "CountryName"), "")