# The ViewData item that has the key 'JobTitleID' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Following a tutorial, and have followed it step-by-step but get an error when I want to edit a field.

Source Error:

```
     </div>
     <div class="editor-field">
         @Html.DropDownList("JobTitleID", String.Empty)
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JobTitleID)
     </div>
```

Here's my controller:

```
// POST: /Employee/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "SIN, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, StartDate, Salary, JobTitleID, DepartmentID")] Employee employee)
    {
        try
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Employees.Add(employee);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        catch (DataException dex)
        {
            if (dex.InnerException.InnerException.Message.Contains("IX_Employee_SIN"))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("SIN", "Unable to save changes. Remember, you cannot have duplicate SIN numbers.");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
            }
        }

        DepartmentDropDownList(employee.DepartmentID);
        JobDropDownList(employee.JobTitleID);
        return View(employee);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Employee/Edit/5

    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        Employee employee = db.Employees.Find(id);
        if (employee == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        DepartmentDropDownList(employee.DepartmentID);
        JobDropDownList(employee.JobTitleID);
        return View(employee);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Employee/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID, SIN, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, StartDate, Salary, JobTitleID, DepartmentID")] Employee employee)
    {
        try
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Employees.Add(employee);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

        }
        catch (DataException dex)
        {
            if (dex.InnerException.InnerException.Message.Contains("IX_Employee_SIN"))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("SIN", "Unable to save changes. Remember, you cannot have duplicate SIN numbers.");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
            }
        }

        DepartmentDropDownList(employee.DepartmentID);
        JobDropDownList(employee.JobTitleID);
        return View(employee);
    }


   private void JobDropDownList(object selectedJob = null)
    {
        var dQuery = from d in db.JobTitles
                     orderby d.Title
                     select d;
        ViewBag.JobID = new SelectList(dQuery, "ID", "Title", selectedJob);
    }
    private void DepartmentDropDownList(object selectedDepartment = null)
    {
        var dQuery = from d in db.Departments
                     orderby d.DepartmentName
                     select d;
        ViewBag.DepartmentID = new SelectList(dQuery, "ID", "DepartmentName",selectedDepartment);
    }
```

I'm not really that familiar with MVC, just thought I'd ask what the issue is, and how it can be fixed.

Comment: Which version of MVC are you using? It looks like you're trying to use this extension method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504970(v=vs.108).aspx - perhaps it was introduced in a version later than the one you're using?

Comment: The error suggests that you are trying to bind an integer to a dropdown list which is expecting a IEnumerable of select list items

Comment: It's not clear what your `DepartmentDropDownList` and `JobDropDownList` methods do, btw - that may be the problem...

Comment: try `@Html.DropDownList("JobID", String.Empty)`

Comment: Trying to order them alphabetically.

Comment: this might help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642821/mvc3-dropdownlist-viewbag-issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ViewBag` encapsulate the `ViewData` internally,  so, the message you are getting is about the ViewBag. You have setted the `ViewBag.JobID` on the controller and in your view you are trying to use another key, `JobTitleID`. Try using the right key:

```
@Html.DropDownList("JobID", String.Empty)
```