# Error displaying database values in dropdown box in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, drop-down-menu

I am having an issue on how to display a dropdown list of values in my database.  My database table (Categories) contains 2 columns, which is the Id and Title of the category.  The goal is to provide a dropdown list where a user can select a title that is stored in the table.

Model:

```
public partial class Category
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    private Context db = new Context();
    ViewBag.Category = new SelectList(db.Categories, "Id", "Title");
    return View();
}
```

View:

```
@model MyApp.Models.Category

<p>
     Categories: @Html.DropDownList("Id", "Select a Category")
</p>
```

There error I am getting is in the view that says:

```
There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Id'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are placing in **viewbag's** category key the dropdown items and in view you are passing **"Id"** that is the mistake you need to pass `Category`

Here you are saving it in Category key:

```
ViewBag.Category = new SelectList(db.Categories, "Id", "Title");
```

Try like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Category","Select a Category")
```

Comment: Haha it worked.  I don't really understand why it wanted Category passed in and not the Id.  Will have to keep learning, but thank you!

Comment: because you are setting ViewBag.Category in action so you need to pas the key name in DropDownList

Answer (score 4):

You are not passing the `SelectList` to the `DropDownList()` method but passing the attribute name that is id.

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Category", "Select a Category")
```

To explicitly pass the SelectList object using the overloaded  [DropDownList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492883%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) cast the ViewBag.Category to SelectList.

```
@Html.DropDownList("CategoryNameOfSelect", (SelectList)ViewBag.Category, "Select a Category")
```

> public static MvcHtmlString DropDownList(     this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
>     string name,    IEnumerable selectList,     string
>   optionLabel )

**htmlHelper**
Type: System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper
The HTML helper instance that this method extends.

**name**
Type: System.String
The name of the form field to return.

**selectList**
Type: System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
A collection of SelectListItem objects that are used to populate the drop-down list.

**optionLabel**
Type: System.String
The text for a default empty item. This parameter can be null.

Comment: if we don't pass explicitly ViewBag.Category, it still works i guess

Comment: I think we need to cast it as it gives error if we do not cast it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642821/mvc3-dropdownlist-viewbag-issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
@Html.DropDownList("Category", (SelectList)ViewBag.Category, "Select a Category")
```

**OR**

```
@Html.DropDownList("Category", ViewBag.Category as SelectList, "--Select a Category--")
```