# ASP.NET MVC Populate DropDown thru ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dropdown, populate, viewbag

I am a beginner to ASP.NET MVC technology. 
   In my View page, I have a WebGrid that is bind to data that is passed from Controller. I also want to populate a dropdown list with the list of Tables in the database. I retrieve the tables List from a helper method. I am trying to send the List to the ViewBag and want to populate the dropdown; but can't get it. Some syntax error is only coming or the List is not accessible.

My Controller class :

```
        [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index(int page = 1, string sort = "FirstName", string sortdir = "asc", string search = "")
    {
        int pageSize = 10;
        int totalRecord = 0;
        if (page < 1)
            page = 1;
        int skip = (page * pageSize) - pageSize;
        var data = GetUsers(search, sort, sortdir, skip, pageSize, out totalRecord);

        // Get Tables List
        ViewBag.TableList = DataFiller.GetTableNames();
        ViewBag.TotalRows = totalRecord;

        return View(data);
    }
```

View file :

```
@model List<DataStudio.Models.User>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MemberLayout.cshtml";

<!-- data is used for grid -->
var grid = new WebGrid(canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 10);
grid.Bind(source: Model, rowCount: ViewBag.TotalRows, autoSortAndPage: false);   
}

<!-- ERROR LINE   -->
@Html.DropDownList("tableName", @ViewBag.TableList, "Select Table")
```

ERROR

```
Error   CS1973  'HtmlHelper<List<User>>' has no applicable method named 'DropDownList' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.    1_Views_Member_Index.cshtml Index.cshtml    82  Active
```

The User model doesn't contain any List nor any DropDownList. The drop down is a totally separate combo box, that I want to fill with a List items; it just contains the list of table names from the database.

I am not able to get how do I bind or populate the drop down list with the SelectLiteItem items. I googled a lot, but could not get any example with this scenario. I don't wish to add my List with my model. And, I want to populate the Tables list drop down only once.

Can anyone please help me and guide me how do I achieve the goal. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Tom

UPDATE:
The `DataFilter.GetTableNames()` method

```
       public static List<SelectListItem> GetTableNames()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> tablesList = new List<SelectListItem>();

        string sql = "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'";
        string conStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DMSDbConnectionString"].ToString();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sql, con)) {
                con.Open();
                using(SqlDataReader sdr = com.ExecuteReader() )
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        tablesList.Add(new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Text = sdr["TABLE_NAME"].ToString(),
                            Value = sdr["TABLE_NAME"].ToString()
                        });
                    }
                }

                /*
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);

                DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

                tablesList = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows
                              select new TablesInfo()
                              {
                                  TableCatalog = dr["TABLE_CATALOG"].ToString(),
                                  TableName = dr["TABLE_NAME"].ToString(),
                                  TableSchema = dr["TABLE_SCHEMA"].ToString(),
                                  TableType = dr["TABLE_TYPE"].ToString(),
                              }).ToList();

                    */
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        return tablesList;
    }
```

I had created a class also `TablesInfo` to populate data in it and use strong typed object. But, as couldn't find a way to populate it, so used `SelectListItem`. 
And as it contains only list of tables, so I don't wish it to be populated on every refresh of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Tetsuya stated, you should be using a strongly typed view model.

You can structure your model like this:

```
 public class MyUserCollection
    {
        public List<MyUser> Users { get; set; }
        public SelectList TableList { get; set; }
        public int TotalRows { get; set; }

        public MyUserCollection(string search, string sort, string sortdir, int skip, int pageSize)
        {
            TableList = DataFiller.GetTableNames();

            Users = GetUsers(search, sort, sortdir, skip, pageSize, out totalRecord);
        }
    }
```

Then to create your drop down:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.tableName, Model.TableList as SelectList, "Select Table")
```

Other wise you need to cast your object:

```
@Html.DropDownList("tableName", (SelectList)ViewBag.TableList, "Select Table")
```

Comment: Thank you. I implemented your solution making a separate class gathering all data in it and using as a Model. Thanks a lot.

Comment: as the question is downgraded, I am not able to set your solution as answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `ViewBag` dynamic object which contains `List<User>` directly to a `DropDownList` HTML helper, you need to cast it into `SelectList` instead:

```
@Html.DropDownList("tableName", (SelectList)ViewBag.TableList, "Select Table")
```

Additionally, `DataFiller.GetTableNames()` method call should returns `SelectList` instance:

```
class DataFiller
{
    public SelectList GetTableNames()
    {
        // set select list items here
    }
}
```

NB: I strongly prefer using a strongly typed view model instead using `ViewBag` or `ViewData` to pass a list to HTML helper like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.tableName, Model.TableList as SelectList, "Select Table")
```

Related issue:

[MVC3 DropDownList + ViewBag issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642821/mvc3-dropdownlist-viewbag-issue)

Comment: Thanks. I have a bit confusion - you all are recommending to use strongly typed view model instead of ViewBag. My requirement is to have just list of table names from the DB. So I am retrieving thru a static class method. With the model approach, won't it retrieve the list of tables every time the page is called/refreshed ? If so, that would be calling unnecessary. So I thought of this option. DataFilter returns List<SelectListItem> GetTableNames(). I had created a class for Tables data, but couldn't get way to populate thru that also. Added method in my   question.  Thanks

Comment: Thank you @Tetsuya. As you suggested, I opted the strongly typed view model approach. Actually, I just have @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TableName, Model.TableList, "Select Table", new { class = "form-control" })  code in View to bind it. Model.TableList is of SelectList and their is no need to typecast it also. As I think I was confused a bit with Model, and as Alexander has shown eg of Model, I am selecting his solution as answer. Thanks a lot. I highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Please use below code i hope that will help your query.

```
ViewBag.TableList = DataFiller.GetTableNames();

@Html.DropDownList("ID", new SelectList(ViewBag.TableList, "ID", "Name"));
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: No problem @TruptiDalia

Answer (score 2):

You can actually do it like below too:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.tableName, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.TableList ,"select table")
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution also works; but I opted using it as a strong typed view model.

Comment: will I guess this is can be alternative for those who bump on similar problem..  Glad you solve your issue too.  =)