# Populating Drop down list with ViewBag in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have made a View named ManageSalesman, it has two sub Views named AddOrEdit and it contains a form. Here I want to populate the Vendor companies list in the drop down from the Vendor table in the database, for that I get them in view bag in the following code.

```
ViewBag.Vendor = new SelectList(db.Vendors, "Id", "name");
```

and make drop down list in AddOrEdit by the following line of code.

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CompanyId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Vendor, "Id", "name"), "Select Vendor Company", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

but when I run it, it will show me: Argument null exception "Additional information: Value cannot be null." Kindly tell me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not make a list of selected vendor in a controller.The correct way is as follow.

```
List<Vendor> VendorList = db.Vendors.ToList();
ViewBag.Vendor = new SelectList(VendorList, "Id", "name");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code for creating the dropdown control.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CompanyId, (SelectList)ViewBag.Vendor, "Select Vendor Company", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642821/mvc3-dropdownlist-viewbag-issue) question has more details.

Comment: now i am getting {"The ViewData item that has the key 'CompanyId' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'."} while i think it is in IEnumerable.

Comment: @HacanChamp, for that error, refer [The ViewData item that has the key 'XXX' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o)

Comment: I have added "  ViewBag.Vendor = new SelectList(db.Vendors, "Id", "name"); " in POST Action result but still getting same error.